# Function can see variables declared outside of there scope

Tags: javascript, scope

I wonder why the function can see the variables "a" and "b" even though they are declared and defined outside of the function scope?

```
function whichOneGreater() {
  a > b ? console.log("a: ", a) : console.log("b: ", b);
}

var a = 3/4;
var b = 4/9;

whichOneGreater()
```

if I change the variable name from a to c

```
function whichOneGreater() {
  a > b ? console.log("a: ", a) : console.log("b: ", b);
}

var c = 3/4;
var b = 4/9;

whichOneGreater()
```

then the error happens

```
script.js:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: a is not defined
    at whichOneGreater (script.js:2)
    at script.js:8
```

Edit: I found an article that answers my question well [here](https://robertnyman.com/2008/10/09/explaining-javascript-scope-and-closures/)

Comment: Why wouldn't it be able to see those variables?

Comment: @VLAZ, I thought for the function encapsulation, a function only sees whatever is defined inside its body, not the outside, right?

Comment: it is because of javascript variable hoisting , wherever you define the variable in the file at runtime it always hoist the variable up and declare that

Comment: @Suraj hoisting is completely unrelated in this case.

Comment: @John a function has access to everything in its inner scope *and* every outer scope. Since `a` and `b` are defined in the same scope as `whichOneGreater()`, then the function can see them. If there was another function defined inside `whichOneGreater()`, then it would also have access to `a` and `b`.

Comment: Thank you. I understand it now.